# How to make a list of type in OCaml?

Tags: list, types, ocaml

I have three type :

```
type position = float * float
type node = position
type edge = node * node * float
```

And I'd like to make a list of edge by using a list of node by doing this :

```
let create_type_list nodes_list =
  let rec create_type_list_aux nodes =
    match nodes with
      | [] -> []
      | x::y::l -> Some (x,y, dist2 x y) @ create_type_list_aux l
    in create_type_list_aux nodes_list
```

`dist2` is just a function that calculates the distance between two nodes.

I'm left wondering why such a function can't work and how I could be able to reach my goal of creating a list of type. I have the following error :

```
Error: This variant expression is expected to have type 'a list
       The constructor Some does not belong to type list
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `@`?

Comment: @glennsl to append the current element to the next one? Isn't it how I'm supposed to append elements together to form a list?

Comment: No, `@` concatenates lists, and hence expects a list on both sides. `::` _prepends_ an element to a list. There is no operator to _append_ elements, as that's not a good use for a list.

Comment: @glennsl Thanks. The function doesn't provoke any errors now, however it created another problem, the list type is incorrect, instead of being an ```edge``` list, it has the following type ```(position * position * float) option list```, making it impossible to use it in another function of mine that requires an edge list. Anything wrong with that function causing it not to return an edge list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you're using to build up the list is presumably this:

```
Some (x,y, dist2 x y) :: create_type_list_aux l
```

Indeed this adds an element to the front of the list of type `(position * position * float) option`. However, the type `position` is the same as the type `node`. So this is also type `(node * node * float) option`. This, in turn is the same as `edge option`. So your only problem is that you're adding an `edge option` to your list rather than an `edge`. You might try using this expression instead:

```
(x, y, dist2 x y) :: create_type_list_aux l
```

The only difference is that I removed `Some`, which is a constructor of the `option` type.